# How to update only those who are divisible MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, case

```
update comments
set comment = case
    when id % 7 = 0 then 'The universe is such an amazing thing.'
    when id % 5 = 0 then 'I definitely read the article again.'
    when id % 3 = 0 then 'This is interesting.'
    when id % 2 = 0 then 'Very good article'
end
where id between 1 and 15;
```

It gives me error: Error Code: 1048. Column 'comment' cannot be null!
I want to update only those witch are divisible.
All others that are not divisible I want to leave unchanged.

Comment: When `id` equals 11 or 13 none of the `when` clauses hold, so what is `comment` equal to? You either need more `when` clauses or an `else` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an `else` branch to the `case` expression that leaves the comment untouched when it matches none of the divisors:

```
update comments
set comment = case
    when id % 7 = 0 then 'The universe is such an amazing thing.'
    when id % 5 = 0 then 'I definitely read the article again.'
    when id % 3 = 0 then 'This is interesting.'
    when id % 2 = 0 then 'Very good article'
    else comment
end
where id between 1 and 15;
```

Or you could use a `where` condition:

```
update comments
set comment = case
    when id % 7 = 0 then 'The universe is such an amazing thing.'
    when id % 5 = 0 then 'I definitely read the article again.'
    when id % 3 = 0 then 'This is interesting.'
    when id % 2 = 0 then 'Very good article'
end
where 
    id between 1 and 15
    and (id % 2 = 0 or id % 3 = 0 or id % 5 or id % 7 = 0)
```

If you are really filtering on values between 1 and 15, then this could be simplified:

```
 where id between 1 and 15 and id not in (1, 11, 13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "cases" do not describe every possible case.

13 is not 0 %7, %5, %3 nor %2.

The good practise is to add a `default` case to capture those scenarios, which is labelled `else` in SQL language.

Comment: Thats what Im asking. How to leave those the way they are and change only those divisible without remainder. It's an exam exercise.

Comment: I did not understand your question then (your selected answer made me understand your exercice)